# Loop is forgetting to post data from excel into word using vba

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have this Loop which required me to insert "n Error Resume next"for it to work. However this means sometimes some data is missing, but not all the time. If I don't have "On Error Resume Next" on the second textmarke.pastespecial I get a Run-time error '4198' Command failed. I have tried looking for the error that I am over coming with the "n error resume next" but I can't. Does anyone have any suggestins?

```
   Dim rownum As Integer
   Dim colnum As Integer
   Dim startrow As Integer
   Dim endrow As Integer

   ' Defining the row and colunm to search for the desired cells

    rownum = 1
    colnum = 2

   ' Find everything from start_of_text to end_of_text
    On Error Resume Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte")
    For rownum = 1 To 10000
       Do
          If .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "Start_of_text" Then
             startrow = rownum + 1 ' Add 1 to the row number of "Start_of_text"
          End If
          rownum = rownum + 1

       If (rownum > 10000) Then Exit For

       Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "End_of_text"
       endrow = rownum - 1 ' Minus 1 to the cell number of "End_of_text"

       'Copy everything from startrow until endrow
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte").Range("B" & startrow & ":B" & endrow).Copy

       'Paste the copied reference product name from excel into word and format
       Set textmarke = doc.Bookmarks(Book).Range
       textmarke.PasteSpecial
       doc.Bookmarks.Add Book, textmarke 'Create a new bookmark bellow the previous one

    ' Find everything from start_of_table to end_of_table
       Do
          If .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "Start_of_table" Then
             startrow = rownum + 1 ' Add 1 to the row number of "Start_of_table"
          End If
          rownum = rownum + 1

       If (rownum > 10000) Then Exit For

       Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "End_of_table"
       endrow = rownum - 1 ' Minus 1 to the cell number of "End_of_table"

       'Copy everything between start_of_table to end_of_table
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte").Range("B" & startrow & ":E" & endrow).Copy

       'Paste the copied reference product table from excel into word and format
       Set textmarke = doc.Bookmarks(Book).Range
       textmarke.PasteSpecial
       doc.Bookmarks.Add Book, textmarke 'Create a new bookmark bellow bellow the previous one

    Next rownum
    End With
```

Comment: Which statement gives you the error 4198 when resume next is omitted ?

Comment: Does the Sub run without errors at all if you don't place the `on error resume`

Comment: The Loop works the first round but then on the second Loop the error Comes on the second "textmarke.PasteSpecial". However on the second Loop the data from the first "textmarke.PasteSpecial" is missing but it doesn't come up with an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are running windows Vista =<, there are times that clipboard bug might cause odd behaviour and usually running multiple copy paste commands fast might lock it. You could try releasing clipboard before running the code and see if that helps in cmd run command `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"` and try to execute again.. If it works that might suggest there is some reason why the clipboard bug manifests..

Comment: No if I dont put the on error resume it Fails on the second Loop.

Comment: Where would I put this command just at the start of my Sub?

Comment: Cause when I put it in it says the first % is an invalid character.

Comment: Start cmd (The command console, cmd.exe) and type `echo off | clip` then run it.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what I Need to do to insert the Code could you Show me how you would put it in my Code?

Comment: Okay I added it in the command prompt but the Code still came up with the same error. Any other ideas?